# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addContact' of undefined onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React project and I am currently stocked here with this error below even when it seems all my codes are in order.
I really can't figure out why I am having this error. I have checked both on google and here too. The answers to the questions similar to this didn't
really solve my challenge, hence me coming here to ask, perhaps someone can figure out where exactly I missed something. Thanks guys

Error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addContact' of undefined
onSubmit

```
  52 | 
  53 |  const onSubmit = (e) => {
  54 |    e.preventDefault();
> 55 |    contactContext.addContact(contact);
  56 |    setContact({
  57 |      name: "",
  58 |      sex: "Female",
```

My Codes are given below:

ContactForm.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import ContactContext from "./../../contact/contactContext";

const ContactForm = () => {
  const contactContext = useContext({ ContactContext });
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    name: "",
    sex: "Female",
    dateOfBirth: "",
    resTown: "",
    hometown: "",
    resAddress: "",
    stateOfOrigin: "",
    lgaOfOrigin: "",
    nationality: "",
    regDate: "",
    hospName: "",
    headDoctor: "",
    hospTown: "",
    onDuty: "",
    hospResAddress: "",
    hospState: "",
    hospLga: "",
    birthType: "",
    babyWeight: "",
  });

  const {
    name,
    sex,
    dateOfBirth,
    resTown,
    hometown,
    resAddress,
    stateOfOrigin,
    lgaOfOrigin,
    nationality,
    regDate,
    hospName,
    headDoctor,
    hospTown,
    onDuty,
    hospResAddress,
    hospState,
    hospLga,
    birthType,
    babyWeight,
  } = contact;

  const onChange = (e) =>
    setContact({ ...contact, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    contactContext.addContact(contact);
    setContact({
      name: "",
      sex: "Female",
      dateOfBirth: "",
      resTown: "",
      hometown: "",
      resAddress: "",
      stateOfOrigin: "",
      lgaOfOrigin: "",
      nationality: "",
      regDate: "",
      hospName: "",
      headDoctor: "",
      hospTown: "",
      onDuty: "",
      hospResAddress: "",
      hospState: "",
      hospLga: "",
      birthType: "",
      babyWeight: "",
    });
  };
```

ContactReducer.jsx

```
import {
  GET_CONTACTS,
  ADD_CONTACT,
  DELETE_CONTACT,
  SET_CURRENT,
  CLEAR_CURRENT,
  UPDATE_CONTACT,
  FILTER_CONTACTS,
  CLEAR_CONTACTS,
  CLEAR_FILTER,
  CONTACT_ERROR,
} from "../types";

export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_CONTACT:
      return {
        ...state,
        contacts: [...state.contacts, action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

ContactState.jsx

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import ContactContext from "./contactContext";
import contactReducer from "./contactReducer";

import {
  GET_CONTACTS,
  ADD_CONTACT,
  DELETE_CONTACT,
  SET_CURRENT,
  CLEAR_CURRENT,
  UPDATE_CONTACT,
  FILTER_CONTACTS,
  CLEAR_CONTACTS,
  CLEAR_FILTER,
  CONTACT_ERROR,
} from "../types";

const ContactState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    contacts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "John Doe",
        hospName: "someText",
        dateOfBirth: "sameDate",
        sex: "someText",
        resTown: "someText",
        hometown: "someText",
        resAddress: "someText",
        stateOfOrigin: "someText",
        lgaOfOrigin: "someText",
        nationality: "someText",
        regDate: "someDate",
        headDoctor: "someText",
        hospTown: "someText",
        onDuty: "someText",
        hospResAddress: "someText",
        hospState: "someText",
        hospLga: "someText",
        birthType: "someText",
        babyWeight: "someFigure",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Sara Mathew",
        hospName: "someText",
        dateOfBirth: "sameDate",
        sex: "someText",
        resTown: "someText",
        hometown: "someText",
        resAddress: "someText",
        stateOfOrigin: "someText",
        lgaOfOrigin: "someText",
        nationality: "someText",
        regDate: "someDate",
        headDoctor: "someText",
        hospTown: "someText",
        onDuty: "someText",
        hospResAddress: "someText",
        hospState: "someText",
        hospLga: "someText",
        birthType: "someText",
        babyWeight: "someFigure",
      },
     
    ],
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(contactReducer, initialState);

  // Add Contact
  const addContact = (contact) => {
    contact.id = uuid.v4();
    dispatch({ type: ADD_CONTACT, payload: contact });
  };

  // Delete Contact

  // Set Current Contact

  // Clear Current Contact

  // Update Contact

  return (
    <ContactContext.Provider
      value={{
        contacts: state.contacts,
        addContact,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ContactContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContactState;
```

Comment: `const contactContext = useContext(ContactContext);` Try this?

Answer (score 1):

If you read `useContext` definition:

```
Don’t forget that the argument to useContext must be the context object itself:

Correct: useContext(MyContext)
Incorrect: useContext(MyContext.Consumer)
Incorrect: useContext(MyContext.Provider)
```

So in your case it should be this:

```
const contactContext = useContext(ContactContext );
```

Remove `{}` these in `useContext`